# python run asyncio task in the background

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I want to run asynio task in the background so that below code prints out 'b' once while printing out 'a' recursively. Instead it prints 'a' forever with no 'b'.

It should cancel the task after 3 seconds like shown in the code.

I tried with create_task and event_loops with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# SuperFastPython.com
# example of running an asyncio coroutine in the background
import asyncio
import time
import uuid


async def custom_coro():
    while True:
        print('a')
        time.sleep(1)
        # await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def run_ws():

    await asyncio.wait([
        custom_coro(),
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tasks = {}
    task = asyncio.run(run_ws())
    # task = asyncio.create_task(run_ws())

    task_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    tasks[task_id] = task

    print('b')
    time.sleep(3)

    tasks[task_id].cancel()

    # tasks = asyncio.all_tasks()
    # t = tasks.pop()
    # t.cancel()

    # asyncio.run(run_ws())
    # print('b')
```

Comment: Try an asyncio.sleep instead in your "a" function...sorry it looks like maybe you tried that already!  (Edit)

Comment: It looks like run doesn't return until the runners are complete. Try putting the rest of main in a fn and use an async gather to call them all. The async sleep is also still probably a good idea here.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have `time.sleep()` in parallel with an async task. You can use something like this

```py
import asyncio

async def custom_coro():
    while True:
        print('a')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
task = asyncio.create_task(custom_coro())
print('b')
asyncio.gather(task)
await asyncio.sleep(3)
task.cancel()
print('done')
```

Output -

```
b
a
a
a
done
_GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_GatheringFuture finished exception=CancelledError()>
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

wrapped in main function:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    async def custom_coro():
        while True:
            print('a')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    task = asyncio.create_task(custom_coro())
    print('b')
    asyncio.gather(task)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    task.cancel()
    print('done')
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I am sorry but the code gives me an error : SyntaxError: 'await' outside function. I could not put it into function without error too.

Comment: @tompal18 added the whole thing wrapped in main.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question is that could you make custom_coro running forever in background even if the main function is done?

Comment: I don't think that is possible or recommended with async. You might want to use a new thread or process for that.